# Custom TableViewCell using FirebaseUI and Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebaseui

I am currently trying to use Firebase UI to populate a UITableView with a custom cell. Unfortunately proving difficult, and previous fixes suggested aren't working.

The documentation (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS#using-storyboards-and-prototype-cells) demonstrates this:

```
self.dataSource = FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource(ref: firebaseRef cellClass: YourCustomClass.self cellReuseIdentifier: @"<YOUR-REUSE-IDENTIFIER>" view: self.collectionView)

self.dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: YourCustomClass, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
  // Populate cell as you see fit
  cell.customView = customView;
}

self.collectionView.dataSource = self.dataSource;
```

Copying this and inserting my own TableViewCellClass produces this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(ManageTableViewCell, NSObject) -> Void' to expected argument type '(UITableViewCell, NSObject) -> Void'

I then saw this issue thread (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/16) where one of the Firebase team said that forcing the cast would work like so:

```
 self.dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
  // Populate cell as you see fit, like as below
  var customCell = cell as! CustomTableViewCell;
  let snapshot = obj as! FDataSnapshot; // danger this can be null on deletion!
}
```

However this immediately produces the error:

> Cannot downcast from
>   'UITableViewCell' to a more optional type 'ManageTableViewCell!'

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this. It appears to be a common issue with no real fix.

Comment: What is a `ManageTableViewCell` ? Show us how exactly your populateCellWithBlock looks. Giving us examples from documentation doesnt help much

Comment: I just found the issue @FruitAddict - Have posted in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. The issue is you need to use "prototypeReuseIdentifier" rather than "cellReuseIdentifier".

My working code is as follows:

```
    dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(query: firebaseQuery, prototypeReuseIdentifier: "textCell", view: self.tableView)

    dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in

        var customCell = cell as! ManageTableViewCell

        let snap = obj as! FDataSnapshot

        customCell.label99.text = snap.key as String
    }
```